# how to parse malformed HTML using HTML::Parser

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I am trying to parse an HTML with meta-tag as :

```
<meta name="id" content=""12345.this.is.a.sample:id:required.67890"@abc.com">
```

The html::parser returns this "" empty value instead of the actual value required. This is my code depicting the start event handler:

```
sub start { 
    my ($self, $tagname, $attr, $attrseq, $origtext) = @_;
    if ($tagname eq 'meta') {
        print "Meta found: ", $attr->{ name }, $attr->{content}, "\n";

    } 
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the required value?

Comment: hopefully it is considering only `content=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found out a way to get the content for this particular problem. The **$origtext** variable above gets the value of the *argspec identifier* **text** which is defined in the documentation as :

```
Text causes the source text (including markup element delimiters) to be passed.
```

So, basically,

```
print $origtext;
```

would give me the source text as output:

```
<meta name="id" content=""12345.this.is.a.sample:id:required.67890"@abc.com">
```

I can use a regex to exploit this value contained in `$origtext` and get the desired stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think a quote from [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) is appropriate here:

> On two occasions I have been asked, — “Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?” […] I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.
>
> – *Passages from the Life of a Philosopher* (1864)

This is known as the [Garbage-In, Garbage-Out (GIGO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIGO) principle. In your case, you have malformed HTML. If you feed that to an HTML parser, you'll necessarily get bogus output. The HTML standard is already quite lax to deal with all kinds of common errors, but your example is much more broken.

There is, of course, one solution: Don't treat your input as HTML, but as some derived format where your example happens to be legal input. You'd have to write a custom parser of your own or adapt an existing HTML parser to your needs, but that would work.

However, I think that fixing the source of the input would be easier than writing your own parser. All that is needed is the quotes inside the attribute to be escaped, or for the attribute to use single quotes:

```
<meta name="id" content="&quot;12345.this.is.a.sample:id:required.67890&quot;@abc.com">
<meta name="id" content='"12345.this.is.a.sample:id:required.67890"@abc.com'>
```

Comment: thanks for the input. However, I am not supposed to change the actual html file. I can however load the html into memory while parsing and then change its contents. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @A.I Yes: as long as you can devise clear, unambiguous rules how such input should be parsed, you can implement such rules and do some preprocessing. But it's important to remember that your input is not HTML.